# configure.ac: getting the command line arguments

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I am trying to get the command line arguments of `./configure` in `confdefs.h` using something like:

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([CONFIGURATION], ["$@"], [Configuration commandline parameters])
```

But it gets evaluted to

```
#define CONFIGURATION "darwin12.4.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
AC_INIT([programname], 1.0, ...)
configure_flags="$*"
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([CONFIG_FLAGS], ["$configure_flags"], [Flags passed to configure])
```